# Find and Remove function call with brackets

Tags: python, regex, replace, find

I'm working on a python script that will allow me to remove some attributes from a function call in a Java class. The problem is I can't find the right regex to include both the name of the attribute and the brackets.

The string I'm looking to remove is, as an example, 'withContentDescription("random text")'

What is the correct way to include the () brackets and the random content of those within my code?
    import re

```
filein = '/path/file.java'
fileout = '/path/newfile.java'

f = open(filein,'r')
filedata = f.read()
f.close()

print("Removing Content Descriptor")
newdata = filedata.strip("withContentDescription\)")

f = open(fileout,'w')
f.write(newdata)
print("--- Done")
f.close()
```

I'd like to obtain something like

```
old string: allOf(withId(someinfo), withContentDescription("Text"))
new string:  allOf(withId(someinfo))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `re.sub`

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = 'allOf(withId(someinfo), withContentDescription("Text"))'
print(re.sub(r",\s*(withContentDescription\(.*?\))", "", s))
```

**Output:**

```
allOf(withId(someinfo))
```